# Multiple views in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

I work on some detailed graphics.
I would like to have two windows of the same file open at once, one zoomed in and the other at 100%. This is easy.
But what I can't figure out is how to remove ALL "stuff" from the 100%
I don't want any guides, rulers, Bounding Boxes handles or such only my pixles.
This works in PS using hide extras on the 100% view. But in Illustrator hiding the bounding box for example hides it in both views.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Just curious but are you using Illustrator's Navigator?

Comment: @Matt_2.0  i'm not sure what you mean "using"? Yes I have it open. But I usualy move around using combination of holding space and zooming using the wheel. Don't see what this has to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to control the display of guides, edges, artboard, print tiling, and rulers per-view. Simply switch to the window you want to change and hide/show options. At least I can here with AI 16.0.4 (CS6)

The Bounding Box is special for some reason. The bounding box visibility is not window independent and will either show or hide for all windows. Truth be told, I hate the bounding box in general. It's not needed and was only added to make Corel users more comfortable when switching apps. The only *real* use for *only* the bounding box is to resize area text boxes easier.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I seem to have got rid of most of the overlays, except the 9-slice lines. Also don't I need the bounding box to scale symbols, or did I miss something?

Comment: You really don't *need* the bounding box for anything. If you need to scale via dragging just tap the e key to select the Free Transform Tool.